# Correct placement of state in navigation dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, components, state

I have a Nav component on my website with a bunch of state managing the user hovering over the list items. If the list items OR the dropdown are hovered, the dropdown is shown with the relevant content.

However, I feel that most of the state that is placed in this Nav component should actually be in NavListDropdown, since that logic belongs there, and not the entire Nav element. isShown, dropdownContent could be argued that they belong in NavListDropdown. My question is, is this a code below still a good practice, or should I refactor it?

```
const Nav = (props) => {
  const [isItemHovered, setIsItemHovered] = useState(false);
  const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false);
  const [dropdownContent, setDropdownContent] = useState(null);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);
  const dropdownShownBefore = useRef(showDropdown);

  const mouseEnterHandler = (content, activeItem) => {
    setIsItemHovered(true);
    if (content) setDropdownContent(content);
    if (activeItem) setActiveItem(activeItem);
  };

  const mouseLeaveHandler = () => {
    setIsItemHovered(false);
  };

  // Set previous dropdownShown
  useEffect(() => {
    dropdownShownBefore.current = showDropdown;
  }, [showDropdown]);

  // Hide dropdown after not hovering for a period of time
  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;

    if (isItemHovered) {
      setShowDropdown(true);
    } else {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setShowDropdown(false);
      }, 400);
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [isItemHovered]);

  const listItems = listItemsData.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <NavListItem
        key={i}
        index={i}
        item={item}
        onMouseEnter={mouseEnterHandler}
        onMouseLeave={mouseLeaveHandler}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <nav className={classes.Nav}>
      <ul className={classes.NavList}>{listItems}</ul>
      <NavListDropdown
        isShown={showDropdown}
        isShownBefore={dropdownShownBefore.current}
        content={dropdownContent}
        activeItem={activeItem}
        onMouseEnter={mouseEnterHandler}
        onMouseLeave={mouseLeaveHandler}
      />
      <div className={classes.NavLogo}>Logo</div>
      <div className={classes.NavCart}>
        <NavCart />
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

I tried refactoring it already, however, this results in infinite loops, and me being a beginner, I have not experienced something like this before. I hope someone can find a a way to refactor this better, or inform me on how I should place my states.